# Searching a binary search tree for a specific key by returning 1 or 0

Tags: c

I'm learning about Binary search tree. I'm writing a search function where it recursively returns 1 if it finds the number, otherwise 0.
The problem is I have put an assertion where it is activated if it can not find the correct number.
What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
BSTree tree = emptyTree();
    assert(isEmpty(tree));

    // Insert 7 elements into the tree
    int arr[7] = { 5,10,1,3,7,18,20 }, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        insertSorted(&tree, arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        // Verify that all elements are in the tree
        assert(find(tree, arr[i]));
    }
    assert(!find(tree, 18)); //Here the assert is activated
    assert(!find(tree, 5));
```

Here is my code for the search function

```
int find(const BSTree tree, int data)
{
    if (data == tree->data)
        return 1;
    if (data < tree->data)
        return find(tree->left, data);
    if (data > tree->data)
        return find(tree->right, data);
    else
        return 0;
}

void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data)
{
    if (*tree == NULL)
    {
        *tree = createNode(data);
    }
    else if (data < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insertSorted(&(*tree)->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        insertSorted(&(*tree)->right, data);
    }
}

void displayTree( BSTree * tree )
{
    if ( *tree != NULL )
    {
        displayTree( &( *tree )->left );
        printf( "%d ", ( *tree )->data );
        displayTree( &( *tree )->right );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to step through it with a debugger and check the values?

Comment: Also, as it is, your code can never return 0 and will crash on any number not in the tree

Comment: You don't show the `insertSorted()` code; you don't show the code you've used to print your tree so you know it is safe/complete.  Your `find()` function doesn't handle null pointers (from `tree->left` or `tree->right` being null), and doesn't return 0 ever.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the insert code and i have test it completely working

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time I got told that, I'd probably not be paying attention to SO any more...  You may be satisfied, but you've not shown us that we can trust your code.  However, @litelite pointed out a major part of the problem; my comment points out some issues (as well as sniping about you not providing an MCVE — [MCVE]).

Comment: `assert(!find(tree, 18));` --> `assert(!find(tree, 8));`

Comment: i have put the insertSorted() and the display function as you asked I really appreciate your help

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're missing the test `if(tree == NULL) return 0;` at the top of `find()`.

Comment: @litelite Corner case:  If `tree->data` was a FP with a non-a-number "value", `find()` may return 0.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in this line:

```
assert(!find(tree, 18));
```

You are asserting that 18 is not in the tree, but you have 18 in the array to be inserted into the tree. I think if you want it to be correct, it should be:

```
assert(find(tree, 18));
```

Please let me know if I read your question wrong.

Comment: my assert is telling that it should be activated if it not finding the number
it should be with the !

Comment: This answer is correct — in part.  If the assertions in the loop don't fire, these assertions after the loop should fire.   The loop assertion checks that 5 (`arr[0]`) and 18 (`arr[5]`) are present; the post-loop assertions check that they are absent.  One or the other assertion will fire.

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` function should probably be:

```
int find(const BSTree tree, int data)
{
    if (tree == 0)  // or NULL
        return 0;
    else if (data == tree->data)
        return 1;
    else if (data < tree->data)
        return find(tree->left, data);
    else // if (data > tree->data)
        return find(tree->right, data);
}
```

It's notable that you must have code equivalent to `typedef struct SomeTag { … } *BSTree` somewhere in your system.  On the whole, the answer to [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) is "No".

Your `displayTree()` function is unexpectedly complex because you define it to take a `BSTree *` instead of just a `BSTree`.  It should be:

```
void displayTree(const BSTree tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL)  // or 0
    {
        displayTree(tree->left);
        printf("%d ", tree->data);
        displayTree(tree->right);
    }
}
```

The pointer-to-pointer is necessary in the `insertSorted()` code, or you revise the prototype to:

```
BSTree *insertSorted(BSTree tree, int data).
```

and call it with:

```
tree = insertSorted(tree, data);
```

Both designs are feasible — there are some advantages each way.

---

#### MCVE

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BSTree *BSTree;
struct BSTree
{
    int    data;
    BSTree left;
    BSTree right;
};

void displayTree(BSTree tree);
void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data);
int find(const BSTree tree, int data);

static int isEmpty(const BSTree tree)
{
    return (tree == 0);
}

static BSTree emptyTree(void)
{
    return 0;
}

static BSTree createNode(int data)
{
    BSTree root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
    if (root != 0)
    {
        root->data = data;
        root->left = 0;
        root->right = 0;
    }
    return root;
}

int main(void)
{
    BSTree tree = emptyTree();
    assert(isEmpty(tree));

    // Insert 7 elements into the tree
    int arr[7] = { 5, 10, 1, 3, 7, 18, 20 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        insertSorted(&tree, arr[i]);
    }
    displayTree(tree);
    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        assert(find(tree, arr[i]));
    }
    assert(!find(tree, 19));
    assert(!find(tree, 6));
    return 0;
}

int find(const BSTree tree, int data)
{
    if (tree == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (data == tree->data)
        return 1;
    else if (data < tree->data)
        return find(tree->left, data);
    else // if (data > tree->data)
        return find(tree->right, data);
}

void insertSorted(BSTree *tree, int data)
{
    if (*tree == NULL)
    {
        *tree = createNode(data);
    }
    else if (data < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insertSorted(&(*tree)->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        insertSorted(&(*tree)->right, data);
    }
}

void displayTree(BSTree tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        displayTree(tree->left);
        printf("%d ", tree->data);
        displayTree(tree->right);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 3 5 7 10 18 20
```

#### Assertions firing in the question's code

Note that in the question, there are two trailing assertions:

```
assert(!find(tree, 18)); //Here the assert is activated
assert(!find(tree, 5));
```

As [Devin Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8242696/devin-liu) pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443639/15168), these assertions should fire — you just ran a loop that checked whether the elements of the array were present with `assert(find(tree, arr[i]));`, and both 5 and 18 are in the array (`arr[0]` and `arr[5]`), so the contrary assertion after the checking loop should fire.

Change 18 to 19, and 5 to 6 (say; many other changes are OK too) and the code works, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the assert is still activated but I've made the changes you gave

Comment: The two trailing assertions are wrong.  You inserted a value 18 into the tree; the loop checked that it was present.  You didn't remove it; the standalone test fails to find it absent.  Change the 18 to 19, for example, and the following 5 to 6, say, and you'll be OK.